# Buildfire database userData not working when using get and save

Tags: get, save, buildfire

Hello I am having issues trying to get the buildfire.userData.save and buildfire.userData.get to work. I had to reroute a bunch of the sdk scripts for the buildfire.js to work. But now I receive an error that user is not defined when I attempt to save input data. When I attempt to get data I receive an unhandled packet label. can anyone help?[save error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I44e9.png) [get error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfgtA.png)

Update: I found where they store user as a variable and put it in the script I made, but now I am getting the unhandled packet for get and save functions and idk why...

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in? User data saves to the currently logged in user data set

Comment: I am logged in, I can see the username in the unhandeled packet

Comment: @TehDeathtrap you can find a full working sample for userData in [BuildFire Examples Github](https://github.com/BuildFire/simpleBuildFireJSExamples/tree/master/exampleWidgetUserDataPlugin). passing userToken can be skipped but you must have a logged in user on the widget side and also make sure your SDK is up to date.